# What is the proper way to handle errors in a promise?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise

I've been seeing a couple of different patterns for handling errors.

One is like:

```
let result;

try {
    result = await forSomeResult(param);
} catch {
    throw new Error();
}
```

And the other is like:

```
const result = await forSomeResult(param).catch(() => throw new Error());
```

I prefer the latter since it looks like a cleaner solution. But I've also heard talks that the first solution is better since there could be some race condition where the `.catch` doesn't execute before the next command is run.

I was wondering if someone had a technical answer about why one method is better than the other.

Comment: "*there could be some race condition where the .catch doesn't execute before the next command is run.*" - that's rubbish. Can you point us to those talks to clarify?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there's no reason to `catch` and `throw` or `.catch()` and `throw` unless you're going to do something else inside the catch handler or throw a different error.  If you just want the same error thrown and aren't doing anything else, then you can just skip the `catch` or `.catch()` and let the original promise rejection go back to the caller.

Then, it is generally not recommended that you mix `await` with `.catch()` as the code is not as easy to follow.  If you want to catch an exception from `await`, use `try/catch` around it.  `.catch()` works, it's just not a preferred style if you're already `await`ing the promise.

The **one technical difference** between these two styles:

```
async function someFunc()
     let x = await fn().catch(err => {
         console.log(err); 
         throw err;
     });
     // do something else with x
     return something;
}
```

And, this:

```
async function someFunc()
     let x;
     try {
         x = await fn();
     } catch(err) {
         console.log(err);
         throw err;
     }
     // do something else with x
     return something;
}
```

is if the function `fn()` you are calling **throws synchronously** (which it shouldn't by design, but could by accident), then the `try/catch` option will catch that synchronous exception too, but the `.catch()` will not.  Because it's in an `async` function, the `async` function will catch the synchronous exception and turn it into a rejected promise for you automatically for the caller to see as a rejected promise, but it wouldn't get logged or handled in your `.catch()` handler.

---

**One of the more beneficial cases for `try/catch` with `await`** is when you have multiple `await` statements and you don't need to handle errors on any of them individually.  Then, you can surround them with one `try/catch` and catch all the errors in one place.

```
async function someFunc(someFile) {
    let fileHandle;
    try {
        // three await statements in a row, all using same try/catch
        fileHandle = await fsp.open(someFile);
        let data = await fsp.read(...);
        // modify data
        await fsp.write(...)
    } catch(err) {
        // just log and re-throw
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    } finally {
        // close file handle
        if (fileHandle) {
             await fileHandle.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*It depends*.

Are you going to be calling multiple asynchronous functions that could error? You can wrap them all in a try/catch and perform common error handling without having to repeat yourself:

```
try {
    result = await forSomeResult(param);
    await forSomeOtherResult();
    return await finalResult(result);
} catch { //catches all three at once!
    throw new Error();
}
```

Do you only need to handle errors for this one, specific call? The .catch() pattern is fine. There is no race condition to worry about, `await` waits for the promise to resolve *or* reject, and this includes all success *and* failure callbacks attached to the promise. However, in your example, you're catching an error only to throw an empty one - in that case, it may be preferable to simply write this:

```
const result = await forSomeResult(param);
```

...and let the error propagate to the caller naturally.

I've seen a mixture of both styles used common enough that I think it's fine either way - they each have a particular strength.